# All shortest paths in a DAG (directed acyclic graph)

Tags: shortest-path, directed-acyclic-graphs, floyd-warshall

I have a weighted DAG, with some negative edge weights, and want to find **all** shortest paths in it. Is there any algorithm with complexity better than O(n^2). (My graph is complete i.e. there is an edge (i,j),  for any i,j in {1..n} and i < j ).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Well, a popular algorithm for Path finding is A*. But you can check this article for more information:

[Go to Article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shortest_path_problem)

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The algorithm you're looking for is [Floyd-Warshall](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm), which runs in O(n<sup>3</sup>).

Sometimes you can do better than this by running Djikstra's on every node.  Using a [fibbonacci heap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_heap), you can get O(n<sup>2</sup> log n + ne), where e = number of edges.  It's [even possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm) to get this to work with negative edge-weights!

However, fibbonacci heaps have large constants, so in practice, this approach will only be faster for very sparse graphs.  Since you said your graph is complete, Floyd-Warshall is your best bet.

Comment: As I know, finding the shortest path between any two nodes in a DAG, has the time complexity of O(n+e)=O(n+n^2) in my case of complete DAG. There are O(n^2) of such node pairs, so at the worst case I can find them in O(n^4), which is much lower than O(n!) ! Is it correct?

Comment: @remo: I think we may be speaking about different problems.  Are you looking to find **all** the shortest paths from node A to node B *(there may be more than one shortest path between any two nodes)*?  This is the O(n!) I'm speaking of, and what the above algorithm solves.  Or are you looking to find **a** shortest between node A and node B, for **all** node-pairs A and B?  You are correct that the naive algorithm for this is O(n^4), but somewhat surprisingly, this can [actually be done in O(n^3)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floyd%E2%80%93Warshall_algorithm).

Comment: Yes, of course, I need the second one. Excuse me if I could not convey my question correctly. As you said, I need a shortest path between all nodes A and B. Do you think we can do better than O(n^3), that's the complexity on regular graphs, I think using Floyd.

Comment: @remo: I've edited my answer.  In your case, O(n^3) is the best you can do.